# read div element value in a table in jquery by clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have table structure in html like:

```
<tr class="myTable">
  <div class"Row" id= "myRow">
   <div id=rowID1 > 1 </div>
   <div id=rowID2 > 2 </div>
   <div id=rowID3 > 3 </div>

  </div>
</tr>

<tr class="myTable">
  <div class"Row" id= "myRow">
   <div id=rowID1 > 4 </div>
   <div id=rowID2 > 5 </div>
   <div id=rowID3 > 6 </div>

  </div>
</tr>

<tr class="myTable">
  <div class"Row" id= "myRow">
   <div id=rowID1 > 7 </div>
   <div id=rowID2 > 8 </div>
   <div id=rowID3 > 9 </div>

  </div>
</tr>
```

Each tr is a row of a table and When I click on each row I want to show 1, 4 and 7 which is the first div element. when I tried `console.log(document.getElementById("rowID1").innerHTML);` for every row that I clicked I get "1" but I want it to show different values. I cannot change the IDs (so rowID1 is fixed). any idea of how to get different values by clicking?

Comment: Why can't you change your HTML? It has syntax errors anyway, like `div class"Row"`.

Comment: The `ID` attribute must be unique. Your `Table` is malformed, it lacks the `td` elements.

Comment: If you cannot change your HTML; there's not all that much that can be done to help. There should only be one instance of an `id` per page; and that's where the heart of the issue is.

Comment: That is indeed not a valid html table which should have TDs and also it uses the same IDs over and over. Gladly the IDs are ignored anyhow because they are not surrounded by quotationmarks. It does not even display a table.

Comment: Check this fiddle and bottom one too [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S5NCa/)

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, your HTML is invalid as you need to put `td` elements inside the `tr`, the `id` attributes should be quoted, you are missing an `=` on the row `class` attribute, and you have lots of repeated `id` attributes. Once that's fixed:

```
<table>
    <tr class="myTable">
        <td>
            <div class="Row">
                <div class="rowID1">1</div>
                <div class="rowID2">2</div>
                <div class="rowID3">3</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="myTable">
        <td>
            <div class="Row">
                <div class="rowID1">4</div>
                <div class="rowID2">5</div>
                <div class="rowID3">6</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="myTable">
        <td>
            <div class="Row">
                <div class="rowID1">7</div>
                <div class="rowID2">8</div>
                <div class="rowID3">9</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This jQuery code will work:

```
$('.Row div').click(function() {
    var idx = $(this).index() + 1;
    var values = $('.rowID' + idx).map(function() {
        return this.innerText;
    }).get().join(',');

    alert(values);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/rTU37/)

Comment: hello, What is join? I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'join'

Comment: @user2870274 sorry, my mistake. I was using `join()` twice. See my update. Join is used to convert an array to a string, with the provided delimiter.

Comment: @user2870274 don't forget to accept this answer if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 3):

First in html code should be unique so either remove all "myRow" or change them.
Now, getting value of each div on click on it below code may be solve your problem:

```
<table>
    <tr class="myTable">
        <td>
            <div class="Row">
                <div class="rowID1">1</div>
                <div class="rowID2">2</div>
                <div class="rowID3">3</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="myTable">
        <td>
            <div class="Row">
                <div class="rowID1">4</div>
                <div class="rowID2">5</div>
                <div class="rowID3">6</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="myTable">
        <td>
            <div class="Row">
                <div class="rowID1">7</div>
                <div class="rowID2">8</div>
                <div class="rowID3">9</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Update your html like this. Then here is your solution:-

```
$("table tr").on("click",function(e){

   var targetNode = e.target, parentNode, childNode, firstChildValue,
   hasChild=(targetNode.children.length>0) ? 1:0;

   parentNode = (hasChild) ? targetNode.children[0]: targetNode.parentNode; // get parent node of target node
   child = parentNode.children; // get all its children
   firstChildValue = child[0].innerHTML; // get value of first child
   alert(firstChildValue);
});
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ysNYt/2/)

I hope it will help you.

Comment: thank you so much, suppose I on first row we have three values of 1 ,2 and 3. by using your code, when I click on 3 on first row, it shows 3, because of ( e.target.innerHTML) but I want it to show 1 (which is the first value ) when I click on the row.

Comment: Sorry for earlier mistake, Now I have updated code both here and fiddle please review it.

Comment: Hello again, sorry for late response. Actually I tried your solution it works fine for some rows but sometimes when I click on a row I get a the whole divs inside "Row" class element! for example suppose I click on row 1, I get this:  <div class="rowID1">1</div>
                <div class="rowID2">2</div>
                <div class="rowID3">3</div> and then I should reclick and I get the correct value which is "1". any idea of why it happens sometimes?

Comment: @user2870274 sorry I check it late I made some changes in my code please try this, I hope now it met your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Although your ID may be semantically wrong, being that the ID must be unique, I would assume your ID must be enclosed with quotations.

You have to loop through the ID using each function. [Here's the code I posted over jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vebinua/Sk4pB/)

```
$(function(){

            $('div#myRow').click(function(){

                $('div#rowID1').each(function(){

                    var text = $(this).text();

                    alert(text);

                });
            });
        });
```

Here's to get just the child div with id rowID1:

```
$(function(){
$('div#myRow').click(function(){

    var text = $(this).children('#rowID1').text();

    alert(text);

    });

});
```

Comment: thats so cool man! its so close to what I want but since I want to show the result in a textbox, I want it to show only one value when I click on it. but in your way it shows all the three value at once. Is it possible to show only 1 value when I click on the row table?

Comment: Thanks! I just added an onclick event for each parent row. So you meant only the rowID1 value for specific div (with ID myRow) that is clicked?

Comment: yes, for example, when I click on first row I get 1 second row, 4 and third row 7. For example when I open your jsfiddle I want it to show one value which is 1 but it shows all the three! so the alret opens 3 times but I want it to open one time and show for example 1!

Comment: If you could just restructure your html code then it would be way easier to have this but as you mentioned your ID must be in place so here's a workaround for that. The js fiddle code should be updated now - http://jsfiddle.net/vebinua/Sk4pB/6/. is that what you wanted?

Comment: I've just edited my answer with the latest jsfiddle revision. I'm sorry what "myRow" are you referring to?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this time it showed all the 9 elements at the same time!

Comment: You seem to be looking at the wrong code. Please take a look at the latest revision - http://jsfiddle.net/vebinua/Sk4pB/7/

Answer (score 0):

```
id=rowID1
```

id's MUST be unique and only used once, so your javascript is always going to get the first instance of the id. I would use classes and then do something like this in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.Row').on('click', function(){
        console.log($(this).closest('#rowID1').text());
    });
});
```

Remember to change IDs though, classes should be used

Answer (score 0):

You know, get by id always returned only one element because `id` must be identically, but get by class returned always array, if it found no one, it returned `[]` (empty array). You can check yourself by using `jquery` like that:

`$('#anyId')` <-- it is get by id

`$('.anyClassName')` <-- it is get by class name

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <script src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
      $('.Row div').click(function(e) {
        var currentDiv = $(e.currentTarget);
        currentClass = currentDiv.attr('class');
        console.log($('.' + currentClass).text());
      });

    });
</script>

</head>

<body>
<table>
<tr class="myTable">
  <div class="Row" id= "myRow">
   <div class=rowID1 > 1 </div>
   <div class=rowID2 > 2 </div>
   <div class=rowID3 > 3 </div>

  </div>
</tr>

<tr class="myTable">
  <div class="Row" id= "myRow">
   <div class=rowID1 > 4 </div>
   <div class=rowID2 > 5 </div>
   <div class=rowID3 > 6 </div>

  </div>
</tr>

<tr class="myTable">
  <div class="Row" id= "myRow">
   <div class=rowID1 > 7 </div>
   <div class=rowID2 > 8 </div>
   <div class=rowID3 > 9 </div>

  </div>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```